# Azure App Services die when not used for a couple of weeks

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I'm working on an application that's hosted within Azure using an AppService, it sits behind an Azure Firewall and WAF (for reasons).

Over the Christmas break, most of my test environments went to sleep and never came back (they started dying after between 7 and 16 days of idle time). I could see the firewall attempting to health check them every 2 seconds, but at some point they all stopped responding. The AppService started returning 500.30 errors (which are visible in the AppServiceHttpLogs), but our applications weren't starting, and there were no ApplicationInsights logs (i.e. the app wasn't started/starting).

We also noticed, that if we made any configuration change to any of the environment (not the app) the app would start and behave just fine.

It is worth noting that "AlwaysOn" is configured off, because as far as I'm aware, the startup will just cause some initial request latency (after 20 minutes of idle).

Has anybody got a good suggestion as to what happened, could there be some weird interaction between "AlwaysOn" and AzureFirewall, and if so why did it take weeks before it kicked in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question (partially).

There was an update to azure, which rolled out across our environments over a couple of weeks. After the update there was ~50% change that the automatic restart killed out apps.

The apps were dying because... after a restart, there was a change that the app service route to their keyvault via a vnet, but instead via a public IP, which would be rejected by keyvault.

We determined that this was the issue using kudu --> tools --> diagnostic dump --> (some dump).zip --> LogFiles --> eventlog.xml

If you ever want find app service startup failure stack traces, this is a great place to look.

Now we've got to work out why sometimes keyvault requests don't get routed via vnet, and instead go via the public IP.